# Dynamically add and execute the script tag during two subsequent API calls using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, redux-saga, script-tag

For example:
ApiCall1 has below response:
{ url: 'somescript.js' }

I need to add this url dynamically in script tag like `<script src='somescript.js' async />`
This script should execute and return some data.
This data needs to be immediately sent in the payload of subsequent API call say ApiCall2.

While all this is happening, a loading indicator should be displayed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

calling first shows the loader but after calling the second API doesn't show the loader you can do that in a background process.